# Lamdba aws to access direct IP with the domain in host header

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a small python code which works fine localy but when I run it on AWS it doesn't work.
Instead of calling a domain I'm directing the traffic to an IP and passing the domain under "Host" in headers.
I have an external application which running under 2 different IPs:
Example:
1.1.1.1
and
2.2.2.2

I want to send request to #2 (2.2.2.2).
Lets say that both running the application which configured under my.app.com.
I want to make a request "my.app.com" so it'll route to 2.2.2.2.
Even though the public A record is set to 1.1.1.1.

So when I run this in Python:

```
import urllib.request
headers = {"Host":"my.app.com"}
url = 'http://1.1.1.1'
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url,headers=headers)
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
response = res.read()
```

It works OK from my lock computer but when trying to run it from AWS it fails , eventually the lambda is timing out.

Answer (score 0):

If you configured lambda inside VPC, please make sure it sits in the private subnet and also NAT gateway to access external traffic)